# "Access Denied" Get-windowsFeature -Computername ""

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm trying to run the command:

```
Get-WindowsFeature -ComputerName "example.com"
```

and I got

```
Get-WindowsFeature : Access is denied.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-WindowsFeature -ComputerName "example.com"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : DeviceError: (Microsoft.Manag...rDetailsHandle):CimException) [Get-WindowsFeature], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnSupportedTargetDevice,Microsoft.Windows.ServerManager.Commands.GetWindowsFeatureCommand
```

Can you guys help me to explain how to get those information without getting this error? Do I have to enable something on "example.com" DC?

---

Edit 1:
My approach is I want to ensure that the features on DC's are installed. I would like to run the command `Get-WindowsFeatures` from 1 DC to get all the information from other DC's. At the moment, I'm running with regular user account which has no higher privilege.

Comment: You probably need administrative credentials on `example.com`, and possibly need to run your `Get-WindowsFeature` in an elevated PowerShell session as well.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin any other ways to run it with all regular users by enabling some remote access permission to everyone on the server?. Btw thanks for the answer.

Comment: I cannot imagine a condition where I would want ordinary users doing something like this. Could you edit your question to describe the use-case that requires this?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin added the edit

Comment: @Ender What if you supply the `-Credential` parameter with a domain administrator credential, does that work?

Comment: @Jelphy, it doesn';t work. Still `access is denied"